# Passive mode FTP (vsftpd) error listing directories and timeout

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I'm using a GUI FTP client (WinSCP) to connect the remote FTP server (which is powered by vsftpd on Cent OS).

The GUI logs show that I can connect to the server but it was stucking on retrieving directory listing... and finally timeout!

[image]

[image]

Also I'm following an answer to [vsftpd error Listing Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11837622/1299675) and have configured my `vsftpd.conf`, but still failed.

Anybody some clues?

`vsftpd.conf` sample:

```
dirlist_enable=YES
hide_file=no

ftp_data_port=20
listen_port=21

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=64000
pasv_max_port=64321
port_enable=YES

pasv_address=1**.**.**.**
pasv_addr_resolve=YES

local_root=/var/ftp/pub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to open the port range 64000–64321 in the local firewall on the server. And if there are any external firewalls or NAT's, configure these to allow/route the port range too.

See also a relevant WinSCP article to understand, what [network configuration is needed for the passive FTP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

Comment: Hi the WinSCP guy, open the port range fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Check your VSFTPD logs and take appropriate action.
- If SELinux is enabled check /var/log/audit.audit.log for relevant messages and take appropriate action.
- Ensure that your firewall is configured to allow port 21 and RELATED connections.